# Protocol for onboarding after 2 months notice

Tags: job-offer, new-job, notice-period, follow-up

I accepted a job offer right before Christmas break (both parties have signed and dated the contract). I sent them the signed copy on the 21st. Their offices are closed 17th to 4th.

This is my first job switch, so I was wondering what the protocol is for follow up. It is currently the 3rd of January and I had asked HR for some additional info about medical coverage etc. before Christmas.

I will not be starting until March so I have a few questions:

1. When do I email them about the documents I requested? (I.e.: how long should I wait for their acknowledgment of my acceptance?)
2. When do I follow up about the onboarding process closer to my start date in March?

Comment: You can certainly ask them those questions today via emails. They should be able to respond within this first week of January.

Comment: I regards to acknowledging the signed copy you sent them on the 21st: When sending any type of contracts it's recommended to use registered mail (when sending it physical via regular mail-service) or request read receipt (when sending it via e-mail)..

Comment: @iLuvLogix Note that read receipts are considered by assume people to be rude, as it implies you don't trust the other party. Note that in corporate environments often emails originating from outside the organisation have their read receipt headers stripped.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Interesting point - so when my gov sends me another traffic-fine via registered mail or I sign my next omozan-delivery I can be certainly sure they distrust me and I can safely perceive them as rude?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I don't know what omozan is, but yes, the government doesn't trust you. That's pretty obvious.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie replace o's with a's and the a with an o and then noodle (my favorite search engine) it..

Comment: Amazon. Yes. They don't trust you either. They want to avoid situations where you say you didn't get a package, but you actually did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ask the questions now, both on the documents and the onboarding. There is no reason to wait for acknowledgement, you can assume that they received it and continue directly.

By asking now, you put the ball in the company's court to follow up on this, and it shows pro-activeness. They should give you the information you asked about and you can continue as appropriate afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There's this brand new technology that works pretty effectively when we know that people have been out of the office for a while and are likely sifting through a pile of e-mails.  It has potential to lower a lot of undue stress and anxiety if we use it in a timely fashion.  People are lax to use it nowadays, but it's actually been a huge problem solver since the year 1876.

It's called the t-e-l-e-p-h-o-n-e.

Comment: I think you have a point and is valid to suggest to grab the phone and call. What else can you suggest about this approach? Some pointers or steps would greatly help.